# R ggplot How can I put a boxplot next to a jitterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I produced this plot with ggplot:

```
data <- rnorm(40,mean = 10, sd =3)
df <- data.frame(data)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x="",y = data))+
  geom_boxplot(width=0.2)+
  geom_jitter(width = 0.02,alpha = 0.3, size=1.5)
p
```

[image]

I would like to have the boxplot on the right next to the jitterplot,i.e. that they do not overlap. I know about grids, but I would like to have it in one plot. Position ="dodge" does not help.

I hope my problem is not too confusing. Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3):

With only a single `x` value like this, you could move the boxplot down the axis by mapping a value greater than 1 to `x`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x="", y = data)) +
    geom_jitter(width = 0.02,alpha = 0.3, size=1.5) +
    geom_boxplot(width=0.2, aes(x = 1.25) )
```

[image]

to avoid the unbalanced look of the resulting plot, you could move both layers around the x axis label.  I use `geom_blank` here to keep the axis discrete.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x="", y = data)) +
    geom_blank() +
    geom_jitter(width = 0.02, alpha = 0.3, size = 1.5, aes(x = 1.15) ) +
    geom_boxplot(width=0.2, aes(x = .85) )
```

[image]

Comment: That looks marvelous. However, now everything looks shifted to the right, far away from the y-axis. If I insert a negative value to x, the boxplot merges with the axis. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @00schneider If you want to move the boxplot to the left, use a value less than 1 (like .75).

Comment: Thanks. Maybe last: How can I crop the right part of the plot then. Now there is a big space on the right.

Comment: `ggplot(df, aes(x="", y = data)) +
                geom_jitter(width = 0.02,alpha = 0.3, size=1.5, aes(x = 1.05)) +
                geom_boxplot(width=0.07, aes(x = 0.95)) +  
                theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                     axis.ticks.x=element_blank())` That's just the matter of playing with numbers. This gives you a nice plot. @00schneider

Comment: @00schneider You may want to offset both geoms instead of just one to keep a more balanced look.  See edit.

Comment: Both work wonderfully. Thank you very much!